# @font-face working in Windows browsers but not Mac OSX or iOS?

Tags: ios, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I have a webfont created by Font Squirrel's web font generator. The font displays correctly on all Windows browsers, but does not display on Safari on Mac OSX or IOS. I've also found the same results on Chrome on iOS. I've tried to find the answer to this but no luck.

The following CSS is in an external stylesheet:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mayfieldregular';
    src: url('mayfield-webfont.eot');
    src: url('mayfield-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('mayfield-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('mayfield-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('mayfield-webfont.svg#mayfieldregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

The 4 fonts above are definitely uploaded in the same folder as the CSS stylesheet.

The website also includes a stylesheet which includes CSS such as:
   `h1 { font-family: 'mayfieldregular'; }`

But for some reason this works on Windows but not Mac OSX and iOS. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure on a solution but you might want to start including fallback fonts to cater for times like these, when the fonts aren't loading.

Comment: Thanks, yes I do do that in the actual code, I was just trying to focus on the relevant code so removed it.

Comment: I have answered this question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, the code that I posted in my question did actually work on all systems. The problem was that I had been having a problem where a licensed web font from Myfonts.com didn't work on Macs and iOS, and as a last effort I decided to generate a kit myself at Font Squirrel from the font on my desktop (before writing the above question). When that didn't work either I assumed it was still the same problem, but I've just realised that generating a kit on Font Squirrel did actually fix the Mac/iOS problem. The reason it was continuing not to work was just a basic error.

So if you experience problems displaying your web fonts on Mac OSX and iOS, then consider generating your own kit on Font Squirrel.

Answer (score 0):

I have used .otf font files and they have worked on both Windows and Mac, have you tried that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in theory the fonts above should work on both Windows, Mac OSX and iOS